# How to implement Frame Buster Javascript in iframe

Tags: javascript

I saw this code that could help to solve issue with clickjacking in iframe

```
<style> 
  html { display : none; } 
</style>

<script>
  if( self == top ) {
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    top.location = self.location ;
  }
</script>
```

I didn't understand how does it solve the problem? why `self == top` will solve it ?

Can I use the `ALLOW-FROM`  header or the recommendation is to use both approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of discussion, Mallary's page is the one containing the `<iframe>` element, and Bob's page is the one being put in the frame.

> I didn't understand how does it solve the problem?

Mallary can't clickjack Bob's page if she can't keep it in a frame in the first place.

Of course, this does require that the clickjack attack depends on the Bob's page running JS at all, otherwise Mallary could `sandbox` it so none of its JavaScript runs.

> why `self == top` will solve it ?

It doesn't.

`top.location = self.location;` causes the browser to navigate away from Mallary's page and load Bob's page in its place at the top level of the browser.

`self == top` stops the browser navigating away from Bob's page and loading Bob's page in its place: i.e. it prevents an infinite loop of reloading.

> Can I use the ALLOW-FROM header or the recommendation is to use both approach ?

`X-Frame-Options` is a more effective and less disruptive way to stop a page being loaded into a frame. [A CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) is the more flexible replacement for `X-Frame-Options`.

I would use them instead of JavaScript hacks like this.